# Why does my default value column automatically get populated by a date of January 1, 0001?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

### Table Definition

[image]

### Model Definition

[image]

### Code

```
using MyRandomizer.Models;

namespace MyRandomizer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities())
            {

                Category c = new Category();
                c.Name = "Integral";

                db.Categories.AddObject(c);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Question

Why does my default value column automatically get populated by a date of January 1, 0001?

Comment: I haven't used EntityFramework much yet but does it matter that DefaultValue is empty on your model definition?  This may override sql's default.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but if it's only a CreationDate shouldn't it be Identity instead of Computed? It's not set to change on every row update is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"` in designer it is only included in conceptual model (CSDL). But you also need this in storage model (SSDL). If you don't do it EF will generate INSERT statement which will contain current value of date which is `DataTime.MinValue`. Storage model cannot be edited from designer. You must open EDMX file as XML and manually update row definition.

Final definition should look like:

```
<edmx:Edmx ...>
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <edmx:StorageModels> 
      <Schema ...>
        <EntityContainer Name="...">
          <EntitySet Name="Categories" EntityType="...Categories" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          ...
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Categories"/>
          ...
          <!-- Here you must add StoreGeneratedPattern -->
          <Property Name="CreationDate" Type="datetime" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed" /> 
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    ...
  </edmx:Runtime>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

But this solution has one big problem. Once you manually modify SSDL part you should not use "Update from database" or you will have to perform this change after each call of "Update from database". The reason is that "Update from database" deletes current SSDL part of EDMX and creates new one based on current DB structure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the picture **Model Definition**. The default value is not specified. You database entity doesn't know that the default value. So, it uses the current value of CreationDate. Try to set the default value for your model definition to something sensible.

Comment: how to set the default value to the date on which the row is created?

Comment: I don't have my editor with me, so I can't exactly guide you at the moment. Alternative, you could also set `c.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;` just after you `c.Name = "Integral";`